# Obter o modulo de um número negativo em R

Tags: r

Existe alguma funcao em `R` para obter o modulo de um número negativo ou um vetor de numeros?

exemplo:

```
v <- c(1,-2,3,-4)

module(v)

#> [1]  1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize a função `abs` (valor **abs**oluto):

```
> v <- c(1,-2,3,-4)
> abs(v)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```